# Download Manager Android: Download Complete

Tags: android, android-asynctask, download

I have this application wherein a feature of it will allow you to download a video. The download part is working, but I need to do another function right after the download has been completed. Currently, I am using AsyncTask, but whenever I try to toast on the PostExecute, nothing happens. I'd like to call another function to encrypt then delete the original file after the download has been completed.

And btw, the encryption part is working as well. The only thing I need is something that will allow me to know if the download has been completed.

This is the code where in I'll be downloading the file from a URL. But, I need to know if the download is complete to execute the AsyncTask

```
public void downloadTutorial() throws Exception {
    myURL = "";

    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(myURL));
    request.setTitle(injuryType + " Video");
    request.setDescription("File is being downloaded...");

    request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
    String fileName = URLUtil.guessFileName(myURL, null, MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(myURL));

    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, fileName);

    DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    manager.enqueue(request);

    //if the download is complete execute this
    //new JSONTask().execute();

}
```

The code of the AsyncTask is:

```
   public class JSONTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try {
            Encrypter.encrypt(injuryType);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Download Done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}
```

Comment: i dont know what the problem is but yo ucan try use getApplicationContext (Instead the getActivity)

Comment: There is no problem to the code. I just need to know how to know if the download is complete.

Answer (score 2):

So you want to access the file after downloading the file using Download Manager.
First you will need a Broadcast receiver which will inform you after downloading a file.

In Manifest :

```
<receiver
            android:name="<your download receiver class extends Broadcast receiver>"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:protectionLevel= "signature"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Now you will need to save the download reference id in sharedpref or database
Now save this download reference id in your sharedpref or database so that we can get it in broadcast receiver.

```
  Uri uri = Uri.parse(content.url);
                                            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
                                         request.setDescription("Your App Title").setTitle(<file title>);
                                            request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(getActivity(), Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, <file title>);
                                            request.setVisibleInDownloadsUi(false); //the content will not shown in Download Manager App
                                            mydownlodreference = downloadManager.enqueue(request);
```

Now the main part, in onReceive of BroadcastReceiver class

```
             @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                  DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                    long reference = intent.getLongExtra(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, -1);

     // take out the reference id from your sharedpref or database and check that referenceId with this reference

     DownloadManager.Query query = new DownloadManager.Query();
                query.setFilterById(reference);
                Cursor c = downloadManager.query(query);
                c.moveToFirst();
                int columnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS);
                int status = c.getInt(columnIndex);
                int fileNameIndex = c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_FILENAME);
                String filePath = c.getString(fileNameIndex);
if (status == DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL) {
// do whatever you want here
}

        }
```